# How long does it take to upgrade from Windows 10 1909 (19H2) to Windows 10 2003 (20H1)?

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

I'm currently running Windows 10 Version 1909 (OS Build 18363.448).

When I upgraded from Version 1903, it was a painless process since Windows was using the [Feature Toggle mechanism](https://www.zdnet.com/article/what-to-expect-from-windows-10-november-2019-update-a-pleasant-surprise/) using a small "enablement package" (KB4517245) to switch it on.  There was no dreaded hour-long install where there is a risk of having to wait another hour for roll back.

I'm currently on Slow Ring but I'm interested in installing [Build 19013](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-insider/flight-hub/), the latest Fast Ring release for Windows 10 20H1.  But before I commit to the update (by changing my Insider setting to Fast Ring), what is the process like?  Is it using the small enablement package like 1903 to 1909, or is it like the older style "you cannot do anything while your Windows is installing a new version" style?

Also how much disk space is needed?  I only have 15 GB left.

Comment: How long it takes entirely depends on the machine itself.  When a feature update is installed, user's profile is migrated, just like if you were to upgrade Windows 7 to Windows 10.  *Windows is basically reinstalled, so how long it takes, is entirely based on the specifications of the system and the installation.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this new version running on spare machine with a 7200-rpm hard drive. It installed overnight but ran for nearly an hour before I left it, so it likely took 90 minutes or so, ran through the black or blue text screen:  Updating Windows - do not turn off.  It creates a 25 GB Windows.old file so you will for sure need more space than the 15 GB you have currently.

So very much the "old" process for this new insider version. The shorter update production V1909 is not out yet.

Comment: Thanks.  I cleared enough space, bite the bullet, and pulled the trigger.  Took around 40 minutes even with SSD + IvyBridge i7 CPU.  My windows.old folder after it's done is about 12 GB.  Everything seems to go well, just uncertainty watching the percentage goes from 0% to 100%, with the beginning 60% actually took about 75% of the time.